# Navigation to previous page when Backspace is pressed

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

What to do when I want to navigate back to the previous page in my application by pressing Backspace on my keyboard? I am very new to Vue.js and have no idea how to do that.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Event Handling Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)

Just add a event handler with `@keyup.delete="myFunction"` to your base component and the function will be called. In this function you can implement the navigation (but this depends on wether you use `vue-router` or not)